# How Can I create a new Directory with the last element of the linkedList for each line of the file

Tags: java

I have text file that contain 3 columns ID tweet Classification

I want to create a new Directory for each element of Classification 
so I have created a Linked List to Get Last index and create a directory but it dosent work can you help me fix it? 
thanks 
this is my code:

```
//Create a linked list 
        LinkedList <String> fileLinkedList = new LinkedList<String>();
        fileLinkedList.add(line.toString());//line is a String variable that contains buff.readLine();
        System.out.println(fileLinkedList);

        for(int i = 0; i < fileLinkedList.size();i++){
            File LinkedFile = new File(fileLinkedList.getLast().toString());
            fileLinkedList.add(line);
            System.out.println(fileLinkedList);
            if(LinkedFile.mkdirs()){
                System.out.println("make dir");

            }else{
                System.out.println("doesnt work");
            }


        }
```

Comment: have you tried using Path class? Also OutputStream and InputStream subclasses

Comment: No, I didnt can you tell me why should I use them?  
is my logic wrong here? 
thanks for your response

Comment: well look up on `Path` class its subclass named `Paths` also you can create a new Directory or file by using the OutputStream subclasses and you can read the file content by using the InputStream subclasses note that Input streaam and OutputStream is an abstract class so you cant really create objects from them

Comment: I did use BufferedReader and FileReader to read and create my files but I want to save the file to a linked list and then create a new directory with the name of last element on each line of the file

Answer (score 2):

What I understand is you have a file that contains three columns like this :

```
ID1 tweet1 Classification1
ID2 tweet2 Classification2
ID3 tweet3 Classification3
ID4 tweet4 Classification4
```

You want to read lines of this file, get just `Classification` column and add them to linked list and then create a new directory the name of last element that is `Classification`

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader("File directory"));
LinkedList<String> fileLinkedList = new LinkedList<String>();
String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    fileLinkedList.add(line.split(" ")[2]);

    for(int i = 0; i < fileLinkedList.size();i++){
        File LinkedFile = new File(fileLinkedList.removeLast());

        if(LinkedFile.mkdirs()){
             System.out.println("make dir");

         }else{
             System.out.println("doesnt work");
         }
   }

}
```

And be careful, if you five just a name of directory in `new File()` it creates directories in your project directory of workspace.

Comment: yes, exactly. but it didn't create the files with the name i wanted my file is like this imgur.com/2IsFixY i want to create a new file for all (-1, 0, 3, and so on ) any thing after the third space really thankful for your respond